# How to make two columns the same height and responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make two bootstrap columns the same height and responsive.
So far I have the two columns the same height but as the screen size gets smaller one columns becomes shorter than the other. Like this:

[image]

To make the two columns I used Bootstrap 3. 
My HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-12 pb-20">
      <div class="btn-container">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x500" alt="Snow" style="max-height: 500px;">
        <button class="btn">BREAKFAST MENU</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--
 -->
    <div class="col-md-12 pb-20">
      <div class="btn-container">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x500" alt="Snow" style="max-height: 500px;">
        <button class="btn">DRINKS MENU</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--
 -->
  <div class="col-md-6 hard--right">

    <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:100%;">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200" alt="" style="max-height: 1020px; width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200" style="max-height: 1020px; width:100%" style="width:100%" alt="Second slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200" style="max-height: 1020px; width:100%" alt="Third slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200" style="max-height: 1020px; width:100%" alt="Fourth slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1200" style="max-height: 1020px; width:100%" alt="Fifth slide" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-text hidden-xs">
        <div class="text-center">
          <button class="btn">MAIN MENU</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

The Codepen to my problem is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/dKpdXO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images have `width: 100%`, so when screen resizes they reduce their width based on parent's width (50% of screen width size).

This caused the height of the images to resize too, based on their original aspect ratio.

So this will work if:

right image's height = ( left images height * 2 ) + space between.